# Understanding number of parameters in U(2) by considering action on two component complex vectors

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I'm trying to, perhaps incorrectly, develop an intuition (even if limited) for the number of parameters in elements of U(2), which I understand to be 4, and 3 for SU(2). Broadly speaking I understand the proofs one goes through to determine this by setting up appropriate equations given the unitarity constraint, but I'm trying to come at it from a different direction.

It seems to me by extension of thinking of elements of U(1) as simply rotations of a one-component complex vector we should be able to think of U(2) acting on two-component complex vectors where we, at least initially, have the freedom to rotate and stretch each component independently. Unitarity requires that the magnitude of the two component vector remain unchanged but this can be maintained by trading off the length of one component vector for another.

Said another way we have the freedom to rotate each component in their respective spaces by different angles, and can change their length, so long as the length of the final two-component remains the same. This would seem to give initially 4 parameters - 1 for the constraint giving 3, which is the SU(2) result not U(2). I've read that effectively going from U(2) to SU(2) involves limiting to rotations and ditching reflections, and i'm not sure how reflections fit into the discussion I raised above so maybe that's where i'm falling short of a parameter.

Is it possible to arrive at the correct number of parameters by similar simple reasoning (considering rotations of each component), and if not, why? Do I also need to consider two, two-component vectors and ensure their relative angle remains unchanged?